# Unable to resolve module @react-navigation/material-top-tabs?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabbar

I tried many commands to solve this issue, but i couldnt find the answer, nothing worked. Last, i used

```
npm install react-navigation-tabs
react-native start --reset-cache
```

but they didnt work, i still get the same error.
I installed it as

```
npm install @react-navigation/material-top-tabs react-native-tab-view@^2.16.0
```

and imported this `import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';` but still no, it doesn't work.

this is my package.json as i thought there may be a problem with;

```
{
  "name": "smarthome",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.3.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "native-base": "^2.15.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.8.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't seem to have ```react-native-tab-view@^2.16.0``` in your ```package.json```, you have ```"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.1"``` instead, i guess that can cause that problem

Comment: thanks for replying. I installed it..  `npm uninstall react-native-cli `npx rm -rf node_modules` `npm i global react-native-cli` and started emulator but it gives me error again.  saying "metro has encountered an error SHA-1 for a file " etc.:/ do you know the solution Sir

Comment: okay sir, `    npm install -i -g --force react-native-cli `solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
npm uninstall react-native-cli
npx rm -rf node_modules
npm install -i -g --force react-native-cli
```

those codes solved my problem.